# How to initialize a static non-primitive type in Rust?

Tags: static, rust

I need to have a static std::string::String . I tried initializing it in several ways but in vain. One of them being -

```
static mut DURATION_HEX:String = "0".to_string();
```

I get a note saying :

> note: a limited form of compile-time function evaluation is available
>   on a nightly compiler via `const fn`

I am not able to initialize it. I cannot leave it without initialization as well. 
How do I create a static variable of non-primitive type in rust?

Comment: Use [lazy_static](https://crates.io/crates/lazy_static).

Comment: String need to allocate at runtime so this can't be achieve at compile time. The only solution is lazy static or str.